# ELK Deleting Indexes created with a future Date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an issue with external data (which I have no control over!) being imported into our ELK environment.  The data sometimes contains a future timestamp i.e. One for tomorrow or even further in the future take for example today is 09/08/2016 BST and I have indexes created with dates of 10/08/2016 BST and even 08/09/2016 BST.  As the data isn't of any use, what I would like to do is remove it before it even enters ElasticSearch.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Darren.

Comment: If this is going through logstash you could detect those events before they enter the elasticsearch output and drop them.

Comment: I have tried to find away of doing this, but can't find away of doing a date comparison within Logstash

Comment: You can do it using the `ruby` filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a `ruby` filter.
For illustration purposes, the message I send to stdin is solely composed of a date with the format `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
input {
   stdin {}
}
filter {
   date {
      match => ["message", "dd/MM/yyyy"]
   }
   ruby {
      code => "
         if event['@timestamp'] > Time.now 
           event.cancel
         end
      "
   }
}
output {
   stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

So, if you start logstash with the above config, you get the following output:

```
10/08/2016  <--- today is accepted 
{
       "message" => "10/08/2016",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-08-09T22:00:00.000Z",
          "host" => "iMac-de-Consulthys.local"
}
11/08/2016  <--- tomorrow is dropped
10/09/2016  <--- a date in a month from now is dropped
09/07/2016  <--- a date a month ago is accepted
{
       "message" => "09/07/2016",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-08T22:00:00.000Z",
          "host" => "iMac-de-Consulthys.local"
}
```